# א mi yodeya (the pronunciation)?

Tags: minhag, hebrew, pronunciation, aleph-bet-letters

What is the correct way to pronounce the א (aleph)? Are there variant traditions? Is there an academic/linguistic opinion on how it was most likely pronounced from the time of the giving of the Torah to the writing of the Talmud?

Comment: In all variants I've seen/heard/studied, the aleph is the only letter without ANY distinct pronunciation, unlike the gutteral swallow of the ayin, for instance. AFAIK, it's always pausal/unenunciated.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky No, it's a glottal stop

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes. However, it often appears without a _nekudah_, e.g. בְּרֵאשִׁית, in which case it really is silent. Even when it has a vowel, the glottal stop is frequently skipped, e.g., וְיַאְדִיר

Comment: @Ypnypn Then it's not a consonant and is essentially omitted from pronunciation just like every other matres lectionis. I'm referring to when it's a consonant.

Comment: @DoubleAA Correct. I was just pointing out that א is very often used non-consonantly, and a good answer should elaborate on this.

Comment: @Ypnypn "very often" Of all the matres lectionis it seems to me it is used the least as such by far.

Comment: Please include in this and any similar questions what you seek beyond the wikipedia page of the letter in question. We don't need to reproduce existing common knowledge of the internet.